# Plone 4.0.4 and collective.contentrules.mailtogroup - no group search result

Tags: email, plone

I would be very happy to have "mailtogroup" installed - really - so if someone could tell me how to exactly configure "mailtogroup" in order to sent group email. The problem is that no group names pop up, when I do the search. I was able to setup the single user email facility.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd check if you have the right version of UberSelectionWidget installed. From the documentation for mailtogroup:

> This content rule uses the UberMultiSelectionWidget from plone.app.form. This widget is 
>   broken in version 1.1.7 of plone.app.form. Plone 3.3.4 has this version.
>
> As of version 1.1.8 the widget is working again. To use the correct version pin down 
>   plone.app.form:
>
> [versions] ... plone.app.form = 1.1.8

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks for you answer. The problem is solved - see above in reply to kacee. Have a nice day. Nikolaj

Answer (score 1):

Do you see any errors in the Plone log? You need to be precise when searching for users/groups. Can you try to search for the default 'administrators' group? Are you using the latest version (1.2) of mailtogroup?

Comment: It was a good day yesterday ;-)

collective.contentrules.mailtogroup 1.2 works now (using Plone 4.0.5 on FreeBSD 8.1). The reason why the group is not found is that the group (in question) must be created after installing mailtogroup. Anyway, that is the experience. The install is without pindown of plone.app.form - otherwise error occur.

Thanks to the creators of mailtogroup.
Nikolaj G.

Comment: If you encounter bugs in the content rule you can submit the bug report @  http://plone.org/products/collective.contentrules.mailtogroup/issues